# Rational numbers in irrational bases

Tags: irrational-numbers, rational-numbers, number-systems

If you take the base-$b$ expansion of a rational number where $b$ is irrational, do you get a non-terminating sequence of digits (assuming you pick the right(?) digits)? More informally, do rational numbers look irrational in irrational bases?

Comment: What is a base-$b$ expansion when $b$ is not a positive integer?

Comment: I assume something like base-$\phi$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio_base

Answer (score 2):

Rational numbers in decimal or binary or similar cases can have non-terminating recurring representations, for example $\frac13 = 0.3333333\ldots_{10}= 0.\overline{3}_{10}$.  Presumably you want to include these

Your [golden ratio base link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio_base#Representing_rational_numbers_as_golden_ratio_base_numbers) shows that there are irrational bases in which all rationals can be represented with terminating or recurring expressions. For example $2 = 10.01_{\phi}$ and $\frac12 = 0.\overline{010}_{\phi}$

There are other bases for which this would not be the case - in particular with  transcendental bases (since such a representation would imply a polynomial equation)

Comment: Haha I didn't even notice. But could you possibly prove the transcendental base fact? That sounds really cool and I want to understand it better

Comment: @EyobTsegaye Suppose I had something like $x=12.1\overline{02}_e$.  Then I would know that $x=e^1+2e^0+e^{-1}+2e^{-3}+2e^{-5}+2e^{-7} +\ldots = e+2+e^{-1}+2e^{-3}/(e^{2}-1)$  so $e^6-e^4+(2-x)e^5+e^4-(2-x)e^3-e^2+2 =0$ and if $x$ were rational this would make $e$ algebraic which it is not